# Can't create new Article & Modules - page just reloads

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, error-handling

I've inherited a site, however whenever I try to create a new Article or Module by pressing new. The page just reloads.

Joomla 3: .1.1 | PHP Version :5.4.26 - front end works fine, not seeing any visible php errors in admin.

I'm very lost on how to fix, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, the website should be updated to 3.3.3. Have a backup before trying anything like this though. As for the issue, are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: Hey, So I'll fixed the issues. It all come about when trying to try a 500 error, that I had. So I disabled all my K2 Plugins

Comment: Are you running JCE or other 3rd party plugins? I've seen this happens when you upgrade things like JCE but don't upgrade Joomla. Find the 3.2 update and run that, then run the 3.3 (and back it up first).

Answer (score 1):

I have come across similar things before. The way I fixed this was to log out and clear my browser cache. Them, try logging back in and accessing the article(s) in question.

Answer (score 0):

As a general advise when someone encounters such issues, is to make sure that the Joomla core and all third party extensions are up-to-date. Especially old short-term versions that were not meant for production sites, or are well-known for their buggy behavior and actually they no more receive support.

Also when considering updates, always have backups (tested that work) in place, and it's an all-time recommendation to always test the updates in a dev (testing) version of your website first.